# Multiple conditions while using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I would like to ask if it's possible to have multiple conditions checked while using sed.

Basically I have a text file that can contain strings as follows:

```
a 0000 0000 AA00 0000
a 000000000 AA00 0000
a 0000 0000 BB00 0000
a 0000 0000 CC00 0000
b 0000 0000 AA00 0000
b 0000X0000 BB00 0000
```

1. If columns 12-13 contain 'AA|CC' and column 6 is empty, then add 'Z' to
   column 6.
2. If columns 12-13 contain 'BB' and column 6 is empty, then add
   'ZZ' to column 6.
3. This applies only to rows starting with 'a'.

Therefore, output should be:

```
a 0000Z0000 AA00 0000
a 000000000 AA00 0000
a 0000ZZ0000 BB00 0000
a 0000Z0000 CC00 0000
b 0000 0000 AA00 0000
b 0000X0000 BB00 0000
```

What I have came up with so far is the following.

```
sed -E '/^a(.{12})A|C/s/^(.{6})[\t ]/\1ZZ/g'
```

I think I can eventually do this separately, but I can't figure if it's possible in a one liner and I can't figure it out how to use multiple conditions for double chars.

Any help would be greatly appreciated if possible.

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward implementation in GNU `sed` using extended regular expressions would be:

```
sed -E '
    /^a.{5} .{5}(AA|CC)/s/(.{6})./\1Z/
    /^a.{5} .{5}BB/s/(.{6})./\1ZZ/
' input.txt
```

Or, a bit simpler version:

```
sed -E '
    /^a.{5} .{5}(AA|CC)/s/./Z/7
    /^a.{5} .{5}BB/s/./ZZ/7
' input.txt
```

Replacing the `s/./Z/7` with `{s/./Z/7;b}` might be slightly more efficient, as suggested by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) in the comments.

Comment: This is working as intended in my case and it is very much appreciated. I would like to understand still what is really going on here, and if possible, could you please explain the {5} .{5} part?

Comment: @AlexVieriu `.{5}` means any 5 characters. So, `^a.{5} .{5}` matches a line beginning with `a`, followed by any 5 characters, a space character and any 5 characters.

Comment: Since the two conditions are mutualy exclusive, you can also change `s/./Z/7` to `{s/./Z/7;b}` to immediatly jump to the end of the script when the first condition succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  check=substr($0,13,2)
}
/^a/ && (check=="AA" || check=="CC"){
  print substr($0,1,6) "Z" substr($0,8)
  next
}
/^a/ && check=="BB"{
  print substr($0,1,5) "ZZ" substr($0,8)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  check=substr($0,13,2)                             ##Creating variable check which contains 13t and 14th character of current line.
}
/^a/ && (check=="AA" || check=="CC"){                 ##Checking condition if a line starts from a and check is either equals to AA OR CC then do following.
  print substr($0,1,6) "Z" substr($0,8)             ##Printing sub-string from 1 to 6 characters then Z then rest of the line here.
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^a/ && check=="BB"{                                ##Checking condition if line starts from a AND check is equal to BB then do following.
  print substr($0,1,5) "ZZ" substr($0,8)            ##Printing sub-string from 1 to 5 characters ZZ and rest of line here.
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                                   ##1 will print current line here.
' Input_file                                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This is working as intended as well and while it does the same thing as sed I think I need to reconsider going towards awk. This looks much more pretty than the sed version in my opinion. Thank you for taking the time to reply!

Comment: @AlexVieriu, your welcome and happy to help, will add detailed explanation for above in few mins or so.

Comment: How about a line starting with `b` and check `CC`? Replace `/^a/ && check=="AA" || check=="CC" {` with `/^a/ && (check=="AA" || check=="CC") {`

Comment: @WalterA. thank you I was thinking about it but forgot later made the change now thank you, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^(a.{5})\s(.{5}(AA|CC))/\1Z\2/;s/^(a.{5})\s(.{5}BB)/\1ZZ\2/' file
```

For lines which begin with `a`, followed by 5 characters, a space,5 characters then either `AA` or `CC`, replace the space by `Z`.

For lines which begin with `a`, followed by 5 characters, a space,5 characters then `BB`, replace the space by `ZZ`.

Or you may prefer:

```
sed -E '/^a.{5})\s.{5}(AA|CC)/s/./Z/7;/^a.{5}\s.{5}BB/s/./ZZ/7' file
```